# contar valores duplicados en base de datos de un campo

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, script

hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar
tengo una base de datos llamada usuario  con los campos nombre,  horas, productos
quiero contar la  cantidad de veces que veces que aparce el nombre del usuario y el total de  datos registrados

para el total e datos ya lo tengo es el siguiente codigo

```
public function countTotalUsers()
{
    $sql = "SELECT *FROM usuarios";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

también puedo ver la información en esta tabla

```
   <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
       <thead class="thead-light">
            
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">horas</th>
            <th scope="col">producto</th>  
         <th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php foreach($data as $key => $value): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $value->nom; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value->hora; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value->producto; ?></td>
         

                                                <td>
    
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    
        <tbody id="tbody">
            </table>
```

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://%20https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/377326/como-contar-los-valores-repetidos-de-un-campo)

Answer (score 1):

Contar las veces que se repite un nombre en la columna usuario (el dato repetido)

```
$datos_repetidos=SELECT count(usuario) FROM nombre_de_la_tabla 
WHERE usuario="colocar_aqui_el_valor_del_dato_duplicado";
```

Total de registros que hay en la tabla

```
$contar=$conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) id_usuario FROM usuarios");
$datos_totales=$contar->fetch_assoc();
```

Para imprimir el número total /

```
php echo $datos_totales['id_usuario'];
```

Comment: tengo mas duda en contar datos duplicados

Comment: $datos_repetidos="SELECT  count(Empresa)*FROM levantamiento WHERE Empresa="valor"";

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu duda, no entendí muy bien?